# How to work around the frame.append method is deprecated use pandas.concat instead pandas error

Tags: polygon.io

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

c = WebSocketClient( api_key='APIKEYHERE', feed='socket.polygon.io', market='crypto', subscriptions=["XT.BTC-USD"] )

def handle_msg(msgs: List[WebSocketMessage]): 

    global df
    df = df.append(msgs, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)

c.run(handle_msg)
```

I have a WebSocket client open through polygon.io, when I run this I get exactly what I want but then I get a warning that the frame.append is being deprecated and that I should use pandas.concat instead. Unfortunately, my little fragile brain has no idea how to do this.

I tried doing df = pd.concat(msgs, ignore_index=True) but get TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'polygon.websocket.models.models.CryptoTrade'>';

Thanks for any help